# How to store text in a local file with HTML

Tags: html, local-storage

I'm trying to figure out how to "store" simple text into a .txt file with html.

A Html form page, that you'd input "data/text" into, and it would post the text into the .txt file.

then later you can "get" the data you posted.

Im trying to do this without a server, all local.  (No PHP).

Thanks

Comment: *"Im trying to do this without a server, all local. (No PHP)."* This comes off as a list of demands. You need to post relevant code (html/javascript).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file#answer-13405279

Comment: you need to write it to a comma delimited file witch is just a textfile witch is used instead of a database but you askd the question wrong you cant write it without any javascript, plain html is just that plai, javascript provides funktionality

Answer (score 4):

You can't. You can store data into a Cookie or the browser LocalStorage, but arbitrary filesystem writing isn't possible with just HTML.